# Tablet Homescreen Widgets for Specific Webpages

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, app-widgets

I'm looking for a way to make a custom shortcut on the home screen to open a specific browser to a specific site.  As a hypothetical example, I want to create a shortcut to birdwatch.com/watchnow with the birdwatch.com logo as the shortcut with a custom size and design.

I know how to launch specific apps as a custom widget with KWGT but I am unsure how to launch specific webpages.

I also know how to do it from within a browser but that leaves just a small 1x1 regular shortcut on the screen.

Does anybody know of a solution?

Comment: Typically within each web browser there is a function to create an "desktop icon". Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, but that will only leave a little 1x1 shortcut I cannot customize.  I'm wanting to make a custom-sized widget link with text or an image as the shortcut.  

I'm sort of stuck with it working halfway on both sides.  I can get the link working from a browser shortcut or a fancy link that doesn't go where I want with a widget.

Comment: That you can't customize the link is the fault of the web browser which created it. There are apps that can be used alternatively https://play.google.com/store/search?q=web%20link%20icon%20creator%20launcher&c=apps